# Expectation - product of expectations is expectation of product?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, expected-value

[image][image]I have a random variable $Z(t)$ (which represents the number of cells at time $t$). I know that $Z(t+\Delta t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\Delta t} Z^{k}(t)$ with $Z^{k}(t)$ all independent.

Now it's using this in a calculation involving expectations and probability generating functions that is a problem...

So I have: $$f(x, t + \Delta t) = \mathbb{E} [x^{Z(t+ \Delta t)}] \\ = \mathbb{E} [x^{\sum_{k=1}^{\Delta t} Z^{k}(t)}] \\ =  \mathbb{E}[x^{Z^1(t)} \times x^{Z^2(t)} \times \cdots \times x^{Z^{\Delta t}(t)}] \\ =^{?} \mathbb{E} \prod_{k=1}^{\Delta(t)} \mathbb{E}[x^{Z^k(t)}]$$

My confusion is with the last line. I thought the expectation of a product is the product of expectations, but this is not what has happened. Someone we have managed to get an extra expectation out of the front.

Any ideas?

Edit: attached a picture which is similar where they also turn an expectation of a product in the expectation of a product of expectations. It's a bit differently laid out but the result they've used is identical to what this leads to...

Edit 2: still unsure about what proof is being used.

Comment: The extra expectation doesn't add anything, the product of expectation is not random anymore. I am pretty sure your first intuition was right.

Comment: Indeed where does the outer expectation come from? It is superfluous: $\mathbb{E}(Y_1\cdot \dotso \cdot Y_n)$ is equal to $\mathbb{E}(Y_1)\cdot \dotso \cdot \mathbb{E}(Y_n)$ for any set of $n$ independent RVs $Y_k$, $1 \leq k \leq n$ (where, of course, this applies here to $Y_k=x^{Z^k}$).

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 I think the result is also used in this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Functions_of_independent_random_variables. Attached a screenshot of the wikipedia above too!

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove that is the *law of total expectation* for when you have the number of factors in the product *is also a random variable*. For example let $N$ be an integer valued RV, and $Y_i$ IID with the same mean and independent of $N$. Then $\mathbb{E}(Y_1\cdot \dotso \cdot Y_N)$ can be computed by conditioning on $N=n$ and averaging over the $Y$ and then taking another expectation, averaging over all $N=n$.  Reread it slowly and you will see the difference: $\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}(Y_1 \cdot \dotso \cdot Y_n| N=n)=\mathbb{E}(\mu_Y^n)=g_N(\mu_Y)$ where $g$ is the PGF of $N$

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 I've added a picture of the exact proof where he uses it. Which law is he using in that? He ends up with an expectation of an expectation if I'm correct because the PGF of $z(t + \Delta t) = F(x, t+ \delta t) = \mathbb{E} [x^{Z(t+\Delta t)}]$ but then some other expectation arrives at the end...

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove they appear to be conditioning on the number of products $Z(\Delta t)=K$ and then using the LTE, as I refer to in my previous comment.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Thanks, this gives me a place to start when looking at the proof. If you make it into an answer btw, I will accept!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summing up the comment thread.
Given a deterministic product of $n$ RVs, $Y_i$, provided they are independent, one has
$$\mathbb{E}\left ( \prod_1^n Y_i\right)=\prod_1^n \mathbb{E}(Y_i)$$
If the number of factors itself is an RV, say $N$, and also independent of the $Y_i$ then one can use the [law of total expextation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) to compute the mean:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\prod_1^N Y_i \right)=\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}\left(\prod_1^n Y_i | N=n\right)$$
When the $Y_i$ are IID things simplify further in the usual way before taking the second expectation over $N=n$. In the posted image it appears this is what they are doing by first conditioning on $Z(\Delta t)=K$. Comment for further clarification or any potential errors/typos!

Comment: You know when he talks about PGF for $Z(t + \Delta t)$ and then at the end of the paragraph says 'the pgf is thus...', what is the difference in these two PGFs? Doesn't $\mathbb{E}[x^{(Z(t + \Delta t)}]$ calculate $F(x, t + \Delta t)$? Thanks btw, this is a very weird lecture course with hardly any supplementary resources!

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove To coincide with both notations, each $Y_k=x^{Z^{(k)}(t)}$ is IID. So they all have the same PGF, written as $F(x,t)$ (no dependence on $k$ by IID). This, as a product of $K$ copies, is $F(x,t)^K$. Now complete the application of the LTE by averaging over all possible values $K=Z(\Delta t)$. But this is $\mathbb{E}(F(x,t)^K)$ which is of the form of a PGF itself with $x=F(\cdot,t)$. Does that clarify it?

Comment: Yes! Our lecturer writes unseen results like this down like they're trivial :p